# Copy three columns into one column in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need help to create a Excel VBA macro. I have a workbook contains 4 worksheets. Coulmn "A" in worksheet number 1, 2 and 3 are filled with data. I need to copy these data into Sheet 4 Column "A". I already done this by using this code but it dosn't work (it only copy the data by replacing ..).

EXAMPLE (I need to do following)

```
(Sheet 1 Col. A)
1
2
3
4

(Sheet 2 Col. A)
5
6

(Sheet 3 Col. A)
7
8
9
```

Need to copy all above in sheet 4 Col. A as follows

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

So, I wrote a code as follows

```
Sub CopyColumnToWorkbook()
    Dim sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range

    Set sourceColumn = Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A")
    Set targetColumn = Worksheets("Sheet4").Columns("A")

    sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn
End Sub

Sub CopyColumnToWorkbook2()

    Dim sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range

    Set sourceColumn = Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns("A")
    Set targetColumn = Worksheets("Sheet4").Columns("A")

    sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn
End Sub

Sub CopyColumnToWorkbook2()

    Dim sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range

    Set sourceColumn = Worksheets("Sheet3").Columns("A")
    Set targetColumn = Worksheets("Sheet4").Columns("A")

    sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn
End Sub
```

This above coding is not work as I need. Someone please help me to do as in above EXAMPLE.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quick code I threw together just to get you on the right track. It can be cleaned up. Basically you want to look through each sheet and see what the last column used is, then copy the entire used range for column A, and paste it onto the master sheet, starting from the last cell used in column A. You don't want to paste entire columns, so I used "End(xlUp)" which find the last cell used in column A.

```
Sub ColumnAMaster()

Dim lastRow As Long, lastRowMaster As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Master As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set Master = Sheets.Add
Master.Name = "Master"
lastRowMaster = 1

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If ws.Name <> "Master" Then
        lastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        ws.Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Copy Destination:=Master.Range("A" & lastRowMaster)
        lastRowMaster = Master.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Done!"

End Sub
```

Sorry StackOverflow is not indenting the code as it should...

Things you may want to do: check if there is any data at all inside each sheet before copying A over to the master, loop through worksheets in a specific order, check if a 'master' sheet exists or not already, etc.

Comment: Hi Issun, Thank you very much for your grate help. I cleary undestood your code and it works perfectly of my requirements. Thanks friend again.

Comment: If this answered your questions, please be sure to select the check mark next to the answer to 'accept' it :) Happy I was able to help out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way, very quick and basic but does the job
You could obviously combine all of those 3 do loops into one loop

```
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer

x = 1
y = 1

Do Until Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & x) = ""
    Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A" & y) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & x)
    y = y + 1
    x = x + 1
Loop

x = 1
Do Until Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & x) = ""
    Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A" & y) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & x)
    y = y + 1
    x = x + 1
Loop

x = 1
Do Until Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & x) = ""
    Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A" & y) = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & x)
    y = y + 1
    x = x + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Hi, zoonosis, Thanks for your work. It is grate to decrese the lines of code and it is very helpful to improve my VBA knowledge. Thanks friend.